# Obtaining the current time in android App ( Jetpack Compose + Kotlin) using room database

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Can someone please help me get the current time and date in my app. It is a notes app where whenever I enter the title and description and click save, a note is saved. The problem is I am also using room database and I don't know how to obtain current date and time

I tried using SimpleDateFormat and conversions but the app just crashes. please help

```
@Entity("tableOfNotes")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    @ColumnInfo("Note_Title") val title: String,

    @ColumnInfo("Note_Description") val description: String,

    @ColumnInfo("Note_entryDate") val entryDate: Date = Date.from(Instant.now())
```

)

The Database:

```
    @Database(entities = [Note::class], version =1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConvertor::class)
abstract class NoteDataBase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDataBaseDAO
}
```

The NoteRow file where the note is printed ( the time is required to be displayed here) :

```
@Composable
fun NoteRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, note: Note, onNoteClick: (Note) -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 33.dp))
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        color = Color.LightGray,
        shadowElevation = 6.dp
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier
                .clickable {
                    onNoteClick(note)
                }
                .padding(5.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
            Text(text = note.title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
            Text(text = note.description, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)
            Text(text = note.entryDate.toString(),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall) // for displaying the entry date

        }
    }
}
```

and the dateConvertor:

```
class DateConvertor {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimeStamp(value: Long?) : Date? {
        return value?.let{ Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimeStamp(date: Date?) : Long? {
        return date?.time
    }
}
```

The Crash Logs:
These are the logs:

```
2023-07-26 22:23:20.254  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   I  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-07-26 22:23:20.365  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  DexFile /data/data/com.aarav.jettnote/code_cache/.studio/instruments-45c255fe.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2023-07-26 22:23:20.370  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-07-26 22:23:20.373  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-07-26 22:23:20.375  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
2023-07-26 22:23:20.375  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
2023-07-26 22:23:20.377  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-07-26 22:23:20.384  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-07-26 22:23:20.391  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-07-26 22:23:20.397  2093-2093  Compatibil...geReporter com.aarav.jettnote                   D  Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10075; state: ENABLED
2023-07-26 22:23:20.482  2093-2093  ziparchive              com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~FpntyMU_nF2Ql4412BRnQw==/com.aarav.jettnote-dpjU5AztvSU1W2fn6DJE5Q==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-07-26 22:23:20.482  2093-2093  ziparchive              com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~FpntyMU_nF2Ql4412BRnQw==/com.aarav.jettnote-dpjU5AztvSU1W2fn6DJE5Q==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-07-26 22:23:20.775  2093-2093  GraphicsEnvironment     com.aarav.jettnote                   V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.aarav.jettnote' set to: 'default'
2023-07-26 22:23:20.776  2093-2093  GraphicsEnvironment     com.aarav.jettnote                   V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.aarav.jettnote: false
2023-07-26 22:23:20.776  2093-2093  GraphicsEnvironment     com.aarav.jettnote                   V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2023-07-26 22:23:20.780  2093-2093  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.aarav.jettnote                   D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-07-26 22:23:20.781  2093-2093  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.aarav.jettnote                   D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-07-26 22:23:20.796  2093-2113  libEGL                  com.aarav.jettnote                   D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-07-26 22:23:20.798  2093-2113  libEGL                  com.aarav.jettnote                   D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-07-26 22:23:20.801  2093-2113  libEGL                  com.aarav.jettnote                   D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-07-26 22:23:21.233  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Method boolean androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.conditionalUpdate(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1) failed lock verification and will run slower.
                                                                                                    Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
                                                                                                    and incorrect proguard optimizations.
2023-07-26 22:23:21.233  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Method java.lang.Object androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.mutate(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1) failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-07-26 22:23:21.233  2093-2093  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Method void androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.update(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1) failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-07-26 22:23:21.349  2093-2093  Compatibil...geReporter com.aarav.jettnote                   D  Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10075; state: ENABLED
2023-07-26 22:23:21.418  2093-2111  platform                com.aarav.jettnote                   E  virtgpu backend not enabling VIRTGPU_PARAM_CONTEXT_INIT
2023-07-26 22:23:21.418  2093-2111  platform                com.aarav.jettnote                   E  virtgpu backend not enabling VIRTGPU_PARAM_SUPPORTED_CAPSET_IDs
2023-07-26 22:23:21.419  2093-2111  platform                com.aarav.jettnote                   E  virtgpu backend not enabling VIRTGPU_PARAM_CREATE_GUEST_HANDLE
2023-07-26 22:23:21.419  2093-2111  platform                com.aarav.jettnote                   E  DRM_IOCTL_VIRTGPU_GET_CAPS failed with Function not implemented
2023-07-26 22:23:21.419  2093-2111  platform                com.aarav.jettnote                   E  DRM_IOCTL_VIRTGPU_CONTEXT_INIT failed with Invalid argument, continuing without context...
2023-07-26 22:23:21.419  2093-2111  androidemu              com.aarav.jettnote                   I  HealthMonitor disabled. Returning nullptr
2023-07-26 22:23:21.423  2093-2111  OpenGLRenderer          com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2023-07-26 22:23:21.425  2093-2111  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   E  open_verbose_path:56: Could not open '/dev/goldfish_pipe_dprctd': No such file or directory
2023-07-26 22:23:21.425  2093-2111  .aarav.jettnote         com.aarav.jettnote                   E  open_verbose:128: both vsock and goldfish_pipe paths failed
2023-07-26 22:23:21.435  2093-2111  Gralloc4                com.aarav.jettnote                   I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2023-07-26 22:23:21.443  2093-2111  Gralloc4                com.aarav.jettnote                   W  allocator 4.x is not supported
2023-07-26 22:23:21.559  2093-2111  Parcel                  com.aarav.jettnote                   W  Expecting binder but got null!
--------- beginning of crash
2023-07-26 22:23:21.588  2093-2108  OpenGLRenderer          com.aarav.jettnote                   I  Davey! duration=760ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=2517, IntendedVsync=393220138397, Vsync=393303471727, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=393306723251, AnimationStart=393306727830, PerformTraversalsStart=393306895214, DrawStart=393874197607, FrameDeadline=393236805063, FrameInterval=393306682560, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=393888253223, SyncStart=393889408771, IssueDrawCommandsStart=393890135772, SwapBuffers=393960410755, FrameCompleted=393982027825, DequeueBufferDuration=26495, QueueBufferDuration=309072, GpuCompleted=393981795939, SwapBuffersCompleted=393982027825, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=393960410755, 
2023-07-26 22:23:21.619  2093-2115  AndroidRuntime          com.aarav.jettnote                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
                                                                                                    Process: com.aarav.jettnote, PID: 2093
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number. Expected identity hash: e95272266ee1ffb8863522bd588f5d20, found: 38a98089ce58269a5a9c519611ac64f1
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.kt:147)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:287)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:427)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:232)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:190)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:638)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:457)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:486)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.kt:75)
                                                                                                        at com.aarav.jettnote.data.NoteDataBaseDAO_Impl$9.call(NoteDataBaseDAO_Impl.java:218)
                                                                                                        at com.aarav.jettnote.data.NoteDataBaseDAO_Impl$9.call(NoteDataBaseDAO_Impl.java:215)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$createFlow$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@4f2259c, Dispatchers.IO]
2023-07-26 22:23:21.627  2093-2115  Process                 com.aarav.jettnote                   I  Sending signal. PID: 2093 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What do you mean by current time? Do you want the system time i.e. current time of your device? or some time value that is stored in your room database?

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If I understand correct you want to save your note to room database with the title(you write it), description (you write it) and the date of the creation of the note which will be created automatically? Is that it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in room database using below code.

> **My Data Class Is As Below**

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_files")
data class MyFilesEntity(
    val title: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    val path: String,
    val lastAccessTime: Date,
    val fileCreatedTime: Long,
    val isExist: Boolean,
    val isFavorite: Boolean,
    val isRecent: Boolean,
    val size: Long
)
```

This converter class converts a date to long and vice versa.

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimeStamp(value: Long?) : Date? {
        return value?.let{ Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimeStamp(date: Date?) : Long? {
        return date?.time
    }
}
```

> **Define Converts In Database Like Below**

```
@Database(
    entities = [MyFilesEntity::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(
    Converters::class
)
abstract class PdfDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract val pdfDao : PdfDao
}
```

Hope you are able save date in the room database

Comment: hii the app is still crashing, I have updated the question with the code, can you please check? the app crashes once I add the entryDate thing but without it, it works just fine. Thank you!!

Comment: can you provide crash log please

Comment: I'm sorry I am a little new to android development, can you tell me how do we do so?

Comment: Go to android studio -> LogCat Window and send me that crash log so that I can get real reason

Comment: I have added the logs as an answer to the post because they were too many to fit in the comment. Really Appreciate the Help Sir!!

Comment: There is two way 1). uninstall the app and install it again 2). increase database version. It will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you sir, it did solve my problem although I would love to know the reason for the crash...

Comment: @AaravBansal if you read through the crash log and/or logcat carefully it usually says why the database action failed, and where, though sometimes the actual reason can be buried in the middle of the error list. When changing database details like this it is usually because the database schema of the new compile doesn't match the schema of the app on your emulator or test device.

Comment: @LabGecko Thank you so much for the reply, it really helps the development. I wonder why don't all tutorials teach that at the beginning. 
Thank you once again!! =)